# AngularJS $watches: more simple ones or less complex ones?

Tags: angularjs

Which is better for performance, readability and maintainability (Angular 1.5)?

Less, but more complex watches

```
// component template

<div ng-if="vm.obj.a.b + vm.stuff.c.d + vm.another.thing">
  {{ vm.obj.a.b + vm.stuff.c.d + vm.another.thing }}
</div>
```

Or more, but simpler watches

```
// component template

<div ng-if="vm.sum">
  {{ vm.sum }}
</div>

// component controller...

var vm = this;
$scope.$watch('vm.obj.a.b', fnSum);
$scope.$watch('vm.stuff.c.d', fnSum);
$scope.$watch('vm.another.thing', fnSum);

function fnSum() {
  vm.sum = vm.obj.a.b + vm.stuff.c.d + vm.another.thing;
}
```

Or is there a better way that I'm missing?

This is just a simplified illustration of a situation I come across a LOT.  Please focus on the principle, not this exact example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability and maintainability invoke the function directly from the template:

```
<div ng-show="vm.sum = vm.fnSum()">
  {{ vm.sum }}
</div>
```

JS

```
vm.fnSum = function fnSum() {
    return vm.obj.a.b + vm.stuff.c.d + vm.another.thing;
}
```

Also using `ng-show` avoids creating a new scope.

Be aware that, under the hood, `ng-if`, `ng-show`, and `{{ fn() }}` all create scope watchers. Adding additional watchers for each term of an expression doesn't improve performance.

Comment: Watching a function is supposed to be an Angular performance 'no no', but since you've gotta do that logic anyway, I think your way is as good as it gets. Using the fact that in javascript `x = 'abc'` returns `'abc'` is very clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The latter is better for maintenance reasons:

1. It allows you to put a succinct end-result into the view, allowing anyone scrolling through to simply read the intended output, rather than parts of what will produce the final result. The view remains uncluttered, while the controller can have verbose comments and contain the entire process for getting the `ngIf` determination.
2. It abstracts a potentially volatile result. Say that you needed to change/update what actually triggered `ngIf`; the former would require you to change every instance in the view *along with* whatever controller changes you're making. The latter is simply updating how the final value came to be in the controller, and knowing that the view is already set.

You could probably make the latter a little better by refactoring it into one `$watch`:

```
var vm = this;
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return vm.obj.a.b + vm.stuff.c.d + vm.another.thing;
}, fnSum);

function fnSum(newSum, oldSum) {
  vm.sum = newSum;
}
```

Comment: I agree. Two very good pros.  On the other hand, less code is usually better than more ;)  Any idea about performance?  I guess it's one of those "oh, you have to profile your exact code if you wanna know which performs better..."

Comment: I suppose three watches is a little heavy for one end-result, so you should probably combine them into one (I've edited my answer to include this), but performance-wise, I'd expect one small `$watch` to be pretty similar to Angular's undecorated digest cycle. The function is basically just doing a small summation and assignment. Anything that would really get costly in a `$watch` probably doesn't belong in the view anyway.

Comment: True. I also considered that middle road.  I don't know if it would be faster. Probably more readable/maintainable. I separated the watches because of a desire (that I didn't make explicit in my question) to re-use them: often I have other logic in the template that depends on, say just `vm.obj.a.b`, but not the other two. Then the `vm.obj.a.b` watch could handle both the "other logic" AND call `fnSum`.